# Apt unmet dependencies account-plugin-facebook and google

Tags: apt, kde, dependencies, mate

I'm running Kubuntu 16.04 and I decided to try mate (I guess I must have installed the default ackage but I'm not sure). It was running fine until today when I installed ubuntu-mate-desktop .
The install crashed due to files already present in the KDE archives.
I don't care about the google plugin and I don't have Facebook so I'm really not bothered.

But I can no longer run apt-get commands. apt-get install -f returns the following :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  account-plugin-facebook account-plugin-google
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  account-plugin-facebook account-plugin-google
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/6 222 B of archives.
After this operation, 58,4 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 314495 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../account-plugin-facebook_0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking account-plugin-facebook (0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/account-plugin-facebook_0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/signon-ui/webkit-options.d/www.facebook.com.conf', which is also in package kaccounts-providers 4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1
Preparing to unpack .../account-plugin-google_0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking account-plugin-google (0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/account-plugin-google_0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/accounts/providers/google.provider', which is also in package kaccounts-providers 4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/account-plugin-facebook_0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/account-plugin-google_0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I get it to work again?

Thanks

Comment: you can remove the `ppa `of those packages

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution in another thread:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/account-plugin-facebook_0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1_all.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/account-plugin-google_0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1_all.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```